# Hiding UIView of Parent View From Child View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

[How my screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf4Xi.jpg)

[Master/Parent View Controller Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtBy.png)

[Child View Controller Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TZZG.png)

I want to hide navigation bar and the slider menu in my parent view controller whenever user scrolls down in my child View controller.

> In my child view controller, I have a "scroll view -> view -> text view".
>
> In text view, I have text that comes from API as user scrolls down.

The Red highlight in the master view controller is the container view as seen in image.

How can I hide navigation bar and the slider menu in my parent view controller whenever user scrolls down in my child View controller.

## Is it possible to embed a container view inside the UIScrollView ?

> **If you have any confusion please mention in comment I will answer it thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for navigation bar you could easily check the '*Hide bar*' `On Swipe` property of `UINavigationController`. It hides automatically the nav bar when swipe up and shows it on swipe down.

[image]

But for slider it depends on how you implement that.
You can set `SwipeGestureRecognizer` for it and handle the hidden property programmatically.

**update**
You can use `NSNotification` for notify parent from child.
For that you should declare it in this way:

```
class childViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }

    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
                print("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .swipedDown, object: nil)
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("Swiped left")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .swipedUp, object: nil)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(childScrolledUp(notification:)), name: .swipedUp, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(childScrolledDown(notification:)), name: .swipedDown, object: nil)
    }
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .swipedUp, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .swipedDown, object: nil)
}

    func childScrolledUp(notification: NSNotification) {
        //hide your slider menu
    }

    func childScrolledDown(notification: NSNotification) {
        //show your slider menu
    }
}


extension Notification.Name {
    static let swipedDown = Notification.Name("swipedDown")
    static let swipedUp = Notification.Name("swipedUp")
}
```

Comment: basically the issue is hiding a slider. I am trying to access the view from child view controller

Comment: you can access it from child by `protocol`

Comment: can u please guide me about that a lil bit. Thanks

Comment: sry you can use NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Thank you @arash I was thinking the same to use this trick your code really helped me to do this and after some modification I am done with my think. Thank You so much